# Turning an isometric embedding into a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

While in studying functional analysis, there is a part of a homework problem from Rudin's *Functional Analysis* that asks to show that the isometric embedding $\phi: X \rightarrow X^{**}$ is a homeomorphism onto a dense subset of $X^{**}$ equipped with the weak*-topology, where $X$ is equipped with the weak topology and $X^{**}$ is its bidual.

I think this just follows from applying the fact that every normed-closed subspace of a reflexive space is also reflexive for the subspace $\phi(X)$ of $X^{**}$, given that I have been able to prove this fact as another part of the same problem. I don't think that's enough though. What might I add to make my inference stronger?

Comment: You can't use the result about reflexive spaces. If $X^{\ast\ast}$ is reflexive, $X$ is reflexive, and you have a trivial isomorphism. The interesting case is when $X$ is not reflexive.

Comment: But if $\phi$ is to be a homeomorphism, would that make $X$ reflexive?

Comment: "is a homeomorphism **onto a dense subset**" or, in other words, a topological embedding. You have two things to show. a) $\phi \colon X \to \phi(X) \subset X^{\ast\ast}$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $\phi(X)$, when $X$ carries the weak topology and $\phi(X)$ the weak$^\ast$ topology induced by $X^{\ast\ast}$, and b) $\phi(X)$ is weak$^\ast$-dense in $X^{\ast\ast}$.

Comment: Could we consider using the closed unit ball in $X^{**}$ as our dense subset?

Comment: No, that's not dense. It's weak$^\ast$-compact.

Comment: Right, by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's just clearly lay out what has to be done. In order to not get confused by the different topologies, it might be helpful to introduce different names for the spaces with the different topologies.

Let $E$ be the vector space $X$ endowed with the weak topology induced by $X^\ast$, and let $F$ be the vector space $X^{\ast\ast}$ endowed with the weak$^\ast$ topology induced by $X^\ast$. Let $\psi\colon E \to F$ be the map $x \mapsto (\lambda \mapsto \lambda(x))$, i.e. $\phi$.

Then there are two things to show:

1. $\psi$ is a homeomorphism from $E$ to the subspace $\psi(E) \subset F$, and
2. $\psi(E)$ is dense in $F$.

The first is an immediate consequence of the definition of the weak topology and the weak$^\ast$ topology induced by $X^\ast$, and the second is an easy consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorems.

Comment: Actually, I thought about it for a while, I realized that 1 follows straight from the definitions, as you mentioned. I feel that perhaps 2 was giving me some trouble. Is this related to the Hahn-Banach extension theorem or separation theorem?

Comment: Separation. Theorem 3.5 (3.7 works too) is the one to use. (What is the dual of $E$ resp. $F$?)